# Nim use a input in arrays cannot evaluate at compile time

Tags: nim-lang

I just started working with nim a few days ago and cant figure out why I always get this error: Error: cannot evaluate at compile time: threadcount

```
import strutils

proc thread_test()=
   echo "test"


echo "How many threads do you want to use?"
var threadcount = readLine(stdin)
echo threadcount
var threads: array[threadcount, Thread[void]]


for i in 0..high(threads):
  threads[i].createThread(thread_test)

joinThreads(threads)
echo "i"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First type argument for `array` must be a compile-time constant (e.g. known when the program compiles, not when it runs). So it is not possible to read size from input and use it for `array` - you need to have a dynamic container like `seq`.

There is no particular workaround for that - you can store the number of threads in `const threadCount = 12`, but it also has to be a compile-time constant.

With `seq` your code would be

```
import strutils

proc thread_test()=
   echo "test"


echo "How many threads do you want to use?"
var threadcount = readLine(stdin)
echo threadcount
var threads: seq[Thread[void]]


for i in 0..high(threads):
  threads.add createThread(thread_test)

joinThreads(threads)
echo "i"
```